# How to ignor validation errors of all properties of specific class in ModelState

Tags: model-view-controller, modelstate

I need to ignor validation errors of all properties of specific class in ModelState.
For instance I have view model which contents the Customer class and Customer contents Address class. I need to ignore all validation errors of Address properties.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.Errors.Clear() ? this'll clear the errors, you can always copy them into another collection for reuse.

Comment: Yes, but I want to ignor only Address class errors. I need to keep validation errors of Customer class.

Comment: ModelState.Remove then?